# Jboss default idletimeout minutes if not mentioned

Tags: jboss, connection-pooling

I have a Jboss Standalone EAP version 7.2 server.
There is datasource configured on it.
I dont have the idle timeout for the connections mentioned in the standalone xml. If we dont mention the tag , is the timeout by default 15 minutes?

```
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
```